# Keep spacers even in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

I have `x` number of columns in a table that take up exactly 375px horizontally.  I want to put spacers between them so that the elements span all the way across a variable width.  How is this most easily accomplished?  I'm open to use jQuery.  I'd prefer using CSS for it though.

If I didn't make it clear, the columns are each 375px wide.

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the problem? At the moment, there's too much ambiguity in your question.

Comment: `spacerWidth = (totalWidth - numberOfColumns * columnWidth) / (numberOfColumns - 1)`   maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the columns with content of a fixed or standard width? A table's cells will fill the width of the table, so either

a) provide a standard width for your content cells, and let the spacers calculate their own width based on what is left of the table's total width

b) for every spacer cell, provide a standard width, and leave the widths of the content cells alone, or at least one content cell alone, so that it fills the available width

For what it's worth, when I use tables I try and let the tables do the calculating where possible.

Comment: Solution **b** worked perfectly.  I don't know why I didn't think of that!

Comment: a) or b) almost every time buddy, I promise you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you could to set the td width to `100 / x` percent.
If you have many tables with different amount of columns it'd be easier to set it dynamically with jquery. Otherwise you could do it in css.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a lot like the [flexible box model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) (or FlexBox, if I'm not mistaken). You can get it running with just CSS. Unfortunately, IIRC it only works natively with HTML 5 (or CSS 3, rather). [Here's a good intro to it via Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/19/css3-flexible-box-layout-explained/).

The good news is that there are jQuery plugins / Javascript libraries out there that emulate it for less-capable browsers. Smashmag suggests [Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/).